# Running Simulator shows error Java Runtime Environment does not include developement tools

Tags: codenameone

[image]

Since last week when I try to run the CN1 simulator I see the above message. If I click ok the simulator opens however all sizes of text and images are incorrect (very small). I have added the file path for JAVA_HOME to C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_311 in environment variables, however there is no change. I tried reinstalling java but no change. I ensured development tools were included with the installation. This same issue is showing on 2 other machines. I am using netbeans 8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature discussed in [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-simulator-facelift.html). This weeks update introduced an easy way to disable that using a new menu item.

Comment: Hi Shai thank you for the help and comment. Can you explain where the menu item is? Also, could you comment on the error I see in the question. Also I seem to still have this small font issue mentioned in this closed issue here https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3572

Comment: It's called `Single Window Mode` and was committed here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/905464d2934e2a04863e678add7fbef8896fb7af

Comment: If you have the small font problem you're still using the older maven version and should update to LATEST or 7.0.63

Comment: Thank you for the help Shai. For anyone else who has similar issue. I downloaded and installed Netbeans 13. From there I used https://www.codenameone.com/blog/moving-to-maven.html and https://start.codenameone.com/ to help create a new project with maven. For existing projects use this https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html and this https://github.com/shannah/maven-migration-tool/releases to learn how to migrate existing projects to maven